# why Yup won't check all methods included?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, yup

When I use Yup for password validation, it will check only for the "min" method and not for the "matches" method.
So, if I enter less than 8 characters, I get the error, but if I enter 8 characters or more, and only numbers, it get validate, and does not check for alphanumeric password.

`.matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)` should not check for alphanumeric password?

**this is the code:**

```
    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(8, "Password must be 8 chars long")
      .matches(/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/, "other message..."),
    confirmPswd: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref("password"), null], "password must match"),
  });

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    validationSchema
      .validate({ password, confirmPswd })
      .then(() => {
        mutate({ e, token });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setHelperText({ confirmPswd: error.message });
        console.error("Password is invalid", error);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/` checks that the entered string contains at least 1 (letter OR number). If you want to check for at least 1 letter AND a number, I recommend you split up the regex like so:

Check for letters: `/[a-zA-Z]/`

Check for numbers: `/\d/` (\d is short for 'any digit')

You might modify your code to look something like this:

```js
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(8, "Password must be 8 chars long")
      .matches(/[a-zA-Z]/, "Password must contain a letter")
      .matches(/\d/, "Password must contain a number"),
```

You could try to combine the regexes into one, but in the interest of readability and maintainability, this is cleaner.